# How to add Authorization header to all Glide 4.x request

Tags: android, android-glide

In Glide 3.x we could add register a String model loader like following:

```
public class GlideService /* implements GlideModule*/ {


    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide) {
        glide.register(String.class, InputStream.class, new HeaderedLoader.Factory());
    }

    private static class HeaderedLoader extends BaseGlideUrlLoader<String> {

        public HeaderedLoader(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected String getUrl(String model, int width, int height) {
            return model;
        }


        @Override
        protected Headers getHeaders(String model, int width, int height) {

            LazyHeaders.Builder headersBuilder = new LazyHeaders.Builder();
            if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("staging")) {
                String auth = "username:password";
                String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(auth.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                headersBuilder.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64);
            }

            return headersBuilder.build();
        }

        public static class Factory implements ModelLoaderFactory<String, InputStream> {
            @Override
            public StreamModelLoader<String> build(Context context, GenericLoaderFactory factories) {
                return new HeaderedLoader(context);
            }

            @Override
            public void teardown() { }
        }
    }

}
```

But it's not clear from the docs how we can accomplish this for the lastest version.

Answer (score 3):

I face the same issue as you.
Here is how i fixed it.

1. Your `GlideService` needs to extends `AppGlideModule` (if you are writing code for an application). For more details about this see [glide documentation](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html#applications)
2. As you are now using glide 4.x, your class `HeaderedLoader` now has overriden the two default constructor of `BaseGlideUrlLoader<String>`, these are `protected HeaderedLoader(ModelLoader<GlideUrl, InputStream> concreteLoader)` and `protected HeaderedLoader(ModelLoader<GlideUrl, InputStream> concreteLoader, @Nullable ModelCache<String, GlideUrl> modelCache)`.
3. Create a factory for the `HeaderedLoader` class.
   This should look like

   ```
   static class Factory implements ModelLoaderFactory<String, InputStream> {

       @Override
       public ModelLoader<String, InputStream> build(MultiModelLoaderFactory multiFactory) {
           ModelLoader<GlideUrl, InputStream> loader = multiFactory.build(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class);
           return new HeaderedLoader(loader);
       }

       @Override public void teardown() { /* nothing to free */ }
   }
   ```
4. You will then override the `public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry)` method of glide module super class with the following

   ```
   @Override
   public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        registry.append(String.class, InputStream.class, new HeaderedLoader.Factory());
    }
   ```

You should be able to keep your logic for handling http header inside the `HeaderedLoader` class.
I have use this approach to add custom header to glide request with glide 4.0.

Comment: using prepend(). prepend() will make sure that your ModelLoader or ResourceDecoder is called before all other previously registered components and can run first.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import com.bumptech.glide.load.Options;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.model.GlideUrl;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ModelLoader;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ModelLoaderFactory;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoaderFactory;
import java.io.InputStream;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

/**
 * A simple model loader for fetching media over http/https using OkHttp.
 */
public class OkHttpUrlLoader implements ModelLoader<GlideUrl, InputStream> {

  private final Call.Factory client;

  public OkHttpUrlLoader(Call.Factory client) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean handles(GlideUrl url) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public LoadData<InputStream> buildLoadData(GlideUrl model, int width, int height,
      Options options) {
    return new LoadData<>(model, new OkHttpStreamFetcher(client, model));
  }

  /**
   * The default factory for {@link OkHttpUrlLoader}s.
   */
  public static class Factory implements ModelLoaderFactory<GlideUrl, InputStream> {
    private static volatile Call.Factory internalClient;
    private Call.Factory client;

    private static Call.Factory getInternalClient() {
      if (internalClient == null) {
        synchronized (Factory.class) {
          if (internalClient == null) {
            internalClient = new OkHttpClient();
          }
        }
      }
      return internalClient;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for a new Factory that runs requests using a static singleton client.
     */
    public Factory() {
      this(getInternalClient());
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for a new Factory that runs requests using given client.
     *
     * @param client this is typically an instance of {@code OkHttpClient}.
     */
    public Factory(Call.Factory client) {
      this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public ModelLoader<GlideUrl, InputStream> build(MultiModelLoaderFactory multiFactory) {
      return new OkHttpUrlLoader(client);
    }

    @Override
    public void teardown() {
      // Do nothing, this instance doesn't own the client.
    }
  }
}`
```